# Large Indesign file to ebook

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an 50 MB Indesign book file with +800 images. I would like to convert it to ebook. How can I deal with the size? I know that images can be compressed but any other options? Should I divide it to chapters or parts?

Answer (score 0):

Ebook is text. On top of that, ebook format compresses the text. Reorganising ebook, adding TOC etc... will make very little difference.

Images compression will have a major impact on the file size.

On the other hand - just do it. Ebook file is going to be smaller than InDesign book.

Comment: Thanks! And what is an acceptable size for an ebook?

Comment: I do not think there is a limit. Typical size is 1-2 mb but with images it could be more than that